How to setup a Spring Boot app connecting to MySQL Cloud with IAM authentication with MySQL cloud using PSC endpoint
In GCP, I was able to successfully set up a Spring Boot test app to connect to MySQL Cloud that uses PSC (Private service connect) endpoint using IAM authentication, but it uses the standard MySQL driver, setting the JdBCURL with the PSC ipaddresss and it uses a generateIAMToken method where it uses gcloud sql generate-login token to generate the IAM token.
Was anyone here able to successfully use the Cloud SQL Socket Factory so we don't have to generate the IAM token? When I tried Cloud SQL Socket Factory, it forces to use the instance name instead of the IP address of the PSC endpoint. Having a PSC endpoint, it seems to be required to use the PSC endpoint IP address or else using the instance name, it will not find it and tries to look at the MySQL provided DNS. Note that I am running this Java app in a GKE cluster.
Here was my approach using the direct connection with token generation.
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

// Configure direct connection to PSC IP with cleartext plugin and IAM auth
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://10.x.x.x/dbname?allowCleartextPasswords=true");
config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
config.setUsername("mysqluser");

// Set up IAM authentication
config.setPassword(generateIamToken());
config.addDataSourceProperty("allowPublicKeyRetrieval", "true");

How do I use a socket factory with PSC endpoint?

I have figured it out.,

If you have figured it out, you should post your own answer. It might help someone else in the future.
